# Which subsystem caches file reads?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, vfs

I am trying to understand how exactly file reads are served from Page Cache. This will be useful when I will be implementing my own filesystem in the kernel.

**Is file content  cached by VFS or filesystem or block device?**

Where in kernel source exactly is page cache queried, when read is repeated?